# Cannot render citations in a kable table

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

I am unable to render the citations inside a kable table using neither default pdf_document nor bookdown::pdf_document2 nor html_document. As is shown below,  forcing quotes (") around the citation does not

(Note: the "nocite" is there as a control, nothing in .bib). 
File 'bib.bib' is in the same directory and is as follows:

```
@article{roy2019growth,
  title={Growth pattern and oxygen isotopic systematics of modern freshwater mollusks along an elevation transect: Implications for paleoclimate reconstruction},
  author={Roy, Rupsa and Wang, Yang and Jiang, Shijun},
  journal={Palaeogeography, Palaeoclimatology, Palaeoecology},
  pages={109243},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

### Reprex code

````
---
 output:
    bookdown::pdf_document2
# output: pdf_document
bibliography: bib.bib
---

Citation works, see [@roy2019growth]?


```{r results="asis"}
# using "asis" results
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c("@roy2019growth", "@nocite")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
kableExtra::kable(df)
```


```{r}
# without as is results
kableExtra::kable(df)
```

```{r}
# Try explicit '"' quotes
df <- data.frame(a,b = paste0('"',b,'"'))
kableExtra::kable(df)
```

# My Reference
````

### Session Info

R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] kableExtra_1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        rstudioapi_0.10   knitr_1.23        xml2_1.2.0        magrittr_1.5      hms_0.4.2
 [7] rvest_0.3.4       munsell_0.5.0     viridisLite_0.3.0 colorspace_1.4-1  R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.4.0
[13] highr_0.8         stringr_1.4.0     httr_1.4.0        tools_3.5.3       webshot_0.5.1     xfun_0.8
[19] htmltools_0.3.6   yaml_2.2.0        digest_0.6.20     tibble_2.1.3      bookdown_0.9      crayon_1.3.4
[25] readr_1.3.1       glue_1.3.1        evaluate_0.14     rmarkdown_1.14    stringi_1.4.3     compiler_3.5.3
[31] pillar_1.4.2      scales_1.0.0      pkgconfig_2.0.2

### Rendering .md from .rmd produces desirable output

```
Citation works, see (Roy, Wang, and Jiang 2019)?

    # using "asis" results
    a <- c(1,2)
    b <- c("@roy2019growth", "@nocite")
    df <- data.frame(a,b)
    kableExtra::kable(df)

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:right;">
a
</th>
<th style="text-align:left;">
b
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">
1
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">
Roy, Wang, and Jiang (2019)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">
2
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">
(<span class="citeproc-not-found"
data-reference-id="nocite">**???**</span>)
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

    # without as is results
    kableExtra::kable(df)

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:right;">
a
</th>
<th style="text-align:left;">
b
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">
1
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">
Roy, Wang, and Jiang (2019)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">
2
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">
(<span class="citeproc-not-found"
data-reference-id="nocite">**???**</span>)
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

    # Try explicit '"' quotes
    df <- data.frame(a,b = paste0('"',b,'"'))
    kableExtra::kable(df)

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:right;">
a
</th>
<th style="text-align:left;">
b
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">
1
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">
"(<span class="citeproc-not-found"
data-reference-id="roy2019growth&amp;quot">**???**</span>);
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">
2
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">
"(<span class="citeproc-not-found"
data-reference-id="nocite&amp;quot">**???**</span>);
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

My Reference
============

Roy, Rupsa, Yang Wang, and Shijun Jiang. 2019. “Growth Pattern and
Oxygen Isotopic Systematics of Modern Freshwater Mollusks Along an
Elevation Transect: Implications for Paleoclimate Reconstruction.”
*Palaeogeography, Palaeoclimatology, Palaeoecology*, 109243.
```

Comment: Did you try to produce markdown from rmarkdown first and look at the markdown document?

Comment: Yes the citation is produced within the table when producing .md from .rmd. I have appended the resulting .md to the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@hao-ye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067969/hao-ye) found a great solution, specifying 'markdown' format in kable():`enter code here`

```
kableExtra::kable(dat,
      format = "markdown")
```